# Convert a Text file in to ARFF Format

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, document-classification, arff

I know how to convert a Set of text or web page files in to arff file using TextDirectoryLoader.

I want to know how to convert a single Text file in to Arff file.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example? What is the expected result?

Comment: I used TextDirectoryLoader for converting a collection of web pages in to arff format. Now, I want to convert a single web page in to arff format.I thought to manually copy content of web page in to text file just because of text noises like advertisements and other stuff.

Comment: You don't seem to understand. An ARFF file consists of samples with a class and features. What are your classes? Should there be only one sample representing your web page? Please give an example, you could mean anything with what we now until now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please be more specific. Anyway:

- If the text in the file corresponds to a single document (that it, a
  single instance), then all you need is to replace all "new lines"
  with the escape code `\n` to make the full text be in a single line,
  then manually format as an arff with a single text attribute and a
  single instance.

  If the text corresponds to several instances (e.g. documents), then I
  suggest to make an script to break it into several files and to apply
  `TextDirectoryLoader`. If there is any specific formating (e.g.
  instances are enclosed in XML tags), you can either do the same (by
  taking advantage of the XML format), or to write a custom Loader
  class in WEKA to recognize your format and build an Instances object.

If you post an example, it would be easier to get a more precise suggestion.

Comment: Sir as per your previous answer i converted a set of web pages in to arff format using TextDirectoryLoader.Thanks a lot. I want to convert a single web page in to arff format(Not a Directory having a number of subdirec each representing a class).For text noise(Advertisement and other stuff in a web page) i manually copied only web page content and pasted in a text file. Now i want to convert this text file in to arff file inorder to give it as a Test data.(Say i want to check whether classifier correctly classifies this web page or not).   Thanks a Lot